# When $p(n,m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}n^{k}$, find $(n,m)$ that $p(n,m)$ is square. $n \in \mathbb N,n>1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> When $p(n,m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}n^{k}$, there are no other solution exept $(n,m)=(7,3),(3,4)$ that $p(n,m)$ is square. $n,m \in \mathbb N,n,m>1$.

I got when $m$ is square number, $(1,m)$ is solution.

When $m=2$, 
$n^2 < n^2+n+1<(n+1)^2$

and I got $(7,3)$ and $(3,4)$ for $m=3$ and $4$.

I couldn't find when $m=5$. I didn't think that there are only this solution, but I thought $m=5,6,7,8$ has no solution.

Comment: What is $p(n)$?

Comment: @rtybase I wrote in post,$p(n)=n^m+n^{m-1}+ .......+n^2+n+1$

Comment: Yes, you did, but that is followed immediately by <<no other solution>> which begs for "solution for what?" and as a result "what is $p(n)$?". Whether in fact you are looking for solutions for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}n^k$ being a perfect square.

Comment: @rtybase I found what you confuse of. Yes, I find solution (n,m) that p(n,m) is perfect square. I fix my post about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is given in Ribenboim's book on [Catalan's conjecture](http://books.google.at/books/about/Catalan_s_conjecture.html?id=SOzuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), where all Diophantine equations $$y^2=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^m$$ are studied.

For example, if $m=3$, then only $(x,y)=(1,2)$ and $(x,y)=(7,20)$ are integer solutions, just as you have found.